# What happened to Harry's items?

Tags: the-dresden-files

At the end of *Changes*, Harry ends up in the lake.  At the end of *Ghost Story*, we find him underneath the island with Mab and Demonreach, naked I believe.  When Harry entered the lake he should have had all of his stuff on him as far as I can remember.  Throughout all of *Cold Days* he complains about not having his items.  So, what happened to all of Harry's stuff after *Changes*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as we know, they were lost when Demonreach and Mab saved him from the bottom of lake Michigan. That said, Jim Butcher has a way of bringing items back in a manner that will mess with Harry the most, so I wouldn't be surprised to see them again.

Another perhaps is that now that he has obtained his current position, he has outgrown those items. We already have seen him construct new and improved versions of most of his gear as his skills have grown and his new power level might need new items to be harnessed.

Comment: +1 for scary ways for them to come back. The most logical conclusion is that Mab took them from him, as things like his duster and bracelet wouldn't have easily fallen off his body as it fell.

Comment: unless whatever Demonreach did to transport him only moved Harry and nothing he was carrying. I agree that Mab probably has them, but you never really know. :)

Comment: that's possible too... as Harry did lose everything he was wearing when he walked through Demonreach's defense shield.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield the duster fell apart after the Leanansidhe's enhancement spell ended, so he had already lost that prior to falling overboard.